# Trouble with low level caching in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have some issues with caching in rails. I don't find how should i setting it.
Here's the code :

```
submit_key = nil
pairs_email = Hash.new

pairs_type = Rails.cache.fetch("cache_typeform", :expires_in => 1.day) do
  (0..9).each do
    if submit_key.present?
      url = "https://api.typeform.com/forms/#{typeform_id}/responses?page_size=1000&until=#{submit_key}"
      response = RestClient.get url, {:Authorization => 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXX'}
      parsed = JSON.parse(response.body)
    else
      response = RestClient.get "https://api.typeform.com/forms/#{typeform_id}/responses?page_size=1000", {:Authorization => 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
      parsed = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
    parsed['items'].each do |item|
      pairs_email[item['hidden']['email']] = item['token'] if item['hidden']['email'].present?
    end
    submit_key = parsed['items'][-1]['submitted_at'].chop
  end
end
```

Then it should return a pairs containing an email and an ID and this pairs is used after to get more informations. However, nothing is returning.

Does someone can tell me what I've done wrong in my code? Am I missing something somewhere?

**UPDATE**

I want to use my cache for getting informations from the typeform API :

```
results = Hash.new
if pairs_email[email].present?
  url =  "https://api.typeform.com/v1/form/#{typeform_id}?key=#{ENV['TYPEFORM_API_KEY']}&token=#{pairs_email[email]}"

  response = RestClient.get(url)
  parsed = JSON.parse(response.body)
  results["email"] = parsed["responses"][0]["hidden"]["email"] # Email
  results["first_name"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["textfield_25078009"] # prénom
  results["last_name"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["textfield_25078014"] # nom
  results["phone_number"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["textfield_25444504"] #N°
  results["job"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["textfield_24904749"] # métier
  results["status_legal"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["list_24904751_choice"] # statut légal ?
  results["birthdate"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["date_24904754"] # Date de naissance
  results["zipcode"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["number_24904755"] # Code postal
  results["has_partner"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["yesno_53894471"] # has_partner
  results["children"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["list_53894494_choice"] # Nombre d'enfants
  results["optical_option"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["list_24904752_choice_32209601"] # optical_option
  results["dental_option"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["list_24904752_choice_32209602"] # dental_option
  results["sick_15d"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["list_24904752_choice_32209603"] # Sick_15d
  results["target_year"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["list_24905736_choice"] # target_year
  results["monthly_income"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["number_24904756"] # monthly_income
  results["independent"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["yesno_53895024"] # independent_1_year
  #results["subject_to_discuss"] = parsed["responses"][0]["answers"]["textarea_24904759"] # Avez-vous des sujets dont vous voulez discuter
end
```

Comment: First, check if the response from the api endpoint is successful. 
Second, it may so happen that the key `cache_typeform` already exists in the cache store which points to nil, meaning, the cache key has no value stored in the cache store. You could clear your cache by executing `Rails.cache.clear` from rails console and see if this is not the case. 
Lastly, check again if the response from the api endpoint is fine and you are able to get the desired output by removing the cache block.

Comment: BTW, Dont add any explicit details to your questions which could be misused by others. You really dont need to add the Authorisation detail to your question unless this is publicly available for testing purposes.

Comment: Hi @PamioSolanky, thanks for your answer. i've tried to clear the cache but nothing happened. It does work without caching btw.
Thanks for the Authorisation ! totally forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you must try before getting caching right. Attaching a screenshot from my machine.

Also if you are in development environment you would need to enable caching to see the effect. You could add `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` and `config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }` to your `development.rb` config file to enable caching.

This is just an idea of how caching happens and check if it really works, this should help you get going with your task.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Rails.cache.fetch` stores the value evaluated from the block passed into this method (if there is one, of course). In your example, you're returning `(0..9)` range from the block, instead of actually evaluated `[email id]` pairs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm gonna update my code because I think you will have a better understanding of my issue. Because I tried your solution, but it sill doesn't work.